# Segmentation Fault (core dumped ) : Leitura de array

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, memória

Tenho um problema relacionado com a leitura de um *array* que produz o erro

> Segmentation Fault (core dumped )

Esse é só o começo do desenvolvimento do código, mas já apresenta um erro após ler o primeiro elemento do *array*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void LerArray( int numElementos , float * elemArray ){

  int i;

  float num ;

  for( i = 0 ; i < numElementos ; i++ ){

      printf("Digite um numero para seu array:  ");

      scanf("%f", num );

      *( elemArray + i ) = num ;

      printf("/n/n");


  }


}


int main (){

  int numElementos;

  printf("Oi !!!  Quantos elementos vc quer armazenar :  ");

  scanf("%d", &numElementos );

  system("clear");

  float * vetorNum ;

  vetorNum = ( float * ) malloc( numElementos );

  LerArray( numElementos , vetorNum );

  return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Tens de multiplicar o número de elementos pelo tamanho de cada um

```
vetorNum = malloc(numElementos * sizeof *vetorNum);
```

e verificar se houve erro de alocação de memória

```
if (vetorNum == NULL) /* erro de alocação */;
```

e, quando não precisares mais da memória, libertar os recursos

```
free(vetorNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

O principal que está causando este problema é que você não está alocando a quantidade de *bytes* que precisa para seu vetor.

A função [`malloc()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) armazena um quantidade de *bytes* e não uma quantidade de elementos, então precisaria multiplicar pelo tamanho do tipo do dado de cada elemento.

Também achei um problema no `scanf()` que não estava passando o argumento por referência como deve ser. E o caractere para pular linha também estava errado.

Fora isto, você não está liberando a memória com `free()`. Não causa problema neste caso específico porque o programa é muito pequeno, mas acostume-se fazer isto sempre para não criar vícios.

Nada garante que a alocação deu certo, seria interessante verificar isto.

Então fiz estas modificações e o código ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LerArray(int numElementos , float * elemArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numElementos; i++) {
        float num;
        printf("Digite um numero para seu array:  ");
        scanf("%f", &num);
        *(elemArray + i) = num;
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int main() {
  int numElementos;
  printf("Oi !!!  Quantos elementos vc quer armazenar: ");
  scanf("%d", &numElementos);
  system("clear");
  float * vetorNum;
  vetorNum = malloc(numElementos * sizeof(float));
  if (vetorNum == NULL) {
    printf("Erro na alocação, talvez funcione um um número de elementos menor ");
    return 1;
  }
  LerArray(numElementos, vetorNum);
  free(vetorNum);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L59Qgp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wjfqolgb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/CorrectAllocation.c).

Comment: Valeu bigown. Seu código acima deu certo e no meu caso não precisou verificar erro de alocação ( if(vetorNum == NULL ) ) nem utilizar a função free() como comentou pmg. Obrigado !!

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva Veja o [tour]

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva: o fato de você ter tido sorte e não tenha ocorrido um erro de alocação não significa que você não deva testar se a alocação foi feita com sucesso. Liberar memória é uma boa prática. Em um exercío simples como esse pode não fazer diferença mas é melhor você se acostumar às boas práticas pois quando tiver que trabalhar com programas mais complexos pode fazer uma boa diferença na depuração.